# How to create custom layouts for a web product ?

Tags: html, database, web, database-schema

Is it scalable to store in Database each and every position values for the each components(like buttons and inputs) in a page?
Or is it scalable if we have separate file copy for each user.

Comment: This question needs lots more details to be answerable

Comment: Consider an application jira PM tool which provides custom layouts to its user,Like if I have a web app which has javascript and jquery(html,css..,etc) on front end and Java ,MysQL on back end, How will make custom layouts.

Comment: What do you mean by "scalable"? What do you mean by "database"? What kinds of scenarios are you trying to cater for? How many users? 1000? Millions? Billions? How much data will be stored per user? How frequently will it be written? How frequently will it be read? How up-to-date do reads need to be? Etc.

Comment: scalable means it should serve upto 1 Billion users(different layouts for different user), I am asking if  it is possible if create a table and store user 1 button 1 top 5 px right px..(so on) like that, Write happens if the user want to  change the layout, And also am asking what will be the best way to create an application like that

Answer (score 0):

This question is far too vague to answer with a specific yes or no. Generically, though, there are two main ways to scale a database---scaling up (getting a bigger machine) or scaling out (getting more machines). Which is appropriate will depend on your situation. I suggest you pay an expert to interview you, understand your requirements and offer you advice.